# How would I separate the MotionListener to a different class?

Tags: java, class, paint, circular-reference

I'm trying to teach myself java and I've gotten stumped. I've either been practicing too much today or I'm just having a dumb moment.

I'm playing around with paint and MouseMotionListener to be able to drag graphics across the screen and I wanted to make the MouseMotionListener as a seperate class.

On to the question:

How would I separate the listener in my code into a separate class? When I tried to put it in another class I just ended up making a circular reference.

Code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Class1 extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener{

Point p,p2;


public Class1(){
    p = new Point(0,0);
    this.setSize(500,500);
    //this.setUndecorated(true);
    //this.setBackground(new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.01f));
    this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[]args){
    new Class1();
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.gray);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
}

public void paintSquare(Graphics g){
    g.fillRect(p.x, p.y, 50, 50);
}

public void paintCover(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.gray);
    g.fillRect(p2.x, p2.y, 50, 50);
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    p2=p;
    p=e.getPoint();
    p.translate(-25, -25);
    paintCover(this.getGraphics());
    paintSquare(this.getGraphics());
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    //do nothing
}

}
```

Comment: You **will** (in many cases, such as yours) have a circular reference: The frame will "know" the listener instance, and the listener instance may have a reference back to the frame. However, in any case: Do **NOT** call `getGraphics()` on a Component! Painting this way is plainly **wrong**. See, for example, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/ for an introduction.

Comment: Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) to see how painting should be done...

Comment: Thank you both for the resources. Exactly what I needed to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start be separating your logic into areas of responsibility...

You need:

- Something to render the output
- Something to maintain the current state of the output
- Something to change the current state of the output

Let's start with the model...

The model maintains information about the current state of the output, it provides a means by which the state could be changed and notifications to tell interested parities that the state has changed could be generated.

The view is responsible for rendering the state of the model and listening for changes to the state of the model so that it can update itself when the model changes...

The `MouseMotionListener` (in this case) would be used to modify the state of the model...

The view and the `MouseMotionListener` would both have a reference to the model, this way, the model would act as the bridge between the various components. The `MouseMotionListener` would be used to update the model and the model would trigger notifications to the view, which would paint the current state of the model.

Take a look at [model-view-controller](http://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/) for more details.

Also, custom painting in Swing is generally done by overriding the `paintComponent` method of classes that extend from `JComponent`. You should avoid overriding `paint` of top level containers like `JFrame` or using `getGraphics`.  Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: You explained that so well. Thank you very much

Comment: It's a little abstract, but hits the main points. You'll find if you use the correct painting process, you'll only need to highlight the "current" cell, the previously highlighted cell will be taken care of automatically ;)

Answer (score 0):

`MouseMotionListener` is an interface see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html). The only way you can effectively "remove" it from your `Class1` implementation is to move it to an `abstract` class, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) or create some object that handles the logic required.

You can have an abstract class implement `MouseMotionListener` and override the required methods as defined in `MouseMotionListener` and handle the logic in said abstract class. Then you would `extend` your Class1 with said abstract class.

Please note that you do not **have** to make it an abstract class. You could also have some sort of `MouseMotionHandler` class that could do the same and you would create it and add it to the `JFrame` like so:

```
public class MouseMotionHandler implements MouseMotionListener {
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
       // do something here
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
       //do something here
    }
}
```

And in your `JFrame`

```
MouseMotionHandler mmh = new MouseMotionHandler();
this.addMouseMotionListener(mmh);
```

Another thing you could take a look at is `MouseAdapter`.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html

Here are some references:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077421/learn-java/abstract-classes-vs-interfaces.html
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/

Comment: Sort of, I suppose, except the OP talked about **only** MoustMotionListener

Comment: Yes, what you wrote was technically correct, properly formulated and formatted with infos and links and and such - but it *seems* not to target the core of the question, which (**IF** I understood this correctly) was that your proposed `MouseMotionHandler` would need a reference to the `Class1` instance it belongs to (the "circular reference"). As mentioned in the other comment, this is actually not a problem...

Comment: You are correct in saying that, the circular reference is negligible in this case, and should the OP follow the tutorial you and @MadProgrammer posted; then they will be in an even better state.